# Ошибка заполения базы после миграции LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Привет нужно побороть ошибку.

В Laravel есть таблица. решил вставить поле с помощью миграции.

До миграции

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('descriptions');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

После создания новой миграции
одна строчка в методе up

public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('qrsrc',50)->after('descriptions');
        });
    }

Но возникает ошибка Вероятно в PDO подготовка запроса.

Как ее поменять?? или побороть ошибку.

**Ошибка** SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'qrsrc' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `tasks` (`title`, `descriptions`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ASDASd, dasdasd, 2018-02-05 03:17:23, 2018-02-05 03:17:23))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$fillable в модели забыл указать поле которое только что внес))

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял, Вы пытаетесь добавить запись в БД, не указав то самое поле, которое Вы добавили в новой миграции. А так как Вы не указали, что что столбец qrsrc может принимать значение null, а значение по-умолчанию не установлено, о чем говорится в ошибке **Field 'qrsrc' doesn't have a default value**, то вставить запись не получается.
Я предлагаю решения:

1. Указать в миграции, что столбец может принимать значение null

   ```
   $table->string('qrsrc', 50)->nullable();
   ```
2. Каждый раз при добавлении указывать поле qrsrc

   ```
   insert into tasks (title, descriptions, updated_at, created_at,qrsrc) values (ASDASd, dasdasd, 2018-02-05 03:17:23, 2018-02-05 03:17:23, abcde)
   ```
3. Указать в миграции значение по-умолчанию

   ```
   $table->string('qrsrc', 50)->default('')
   ```

Конкретизирую второй вариант. Нужно явно указывать значение поля *qrsrc* при создании записи в БД, вот примеры:

А) Если запись в БД мы добавляем средствами **[query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)**:

```
DB::table('tasks')->insert(['title' => 'Заголовок', 'descriptions' => 'Описание', 'qrsrc' => 'бла-бла-бла']);
```

Б) Если запись в БД мы добавляем с помощью **[модели](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent)**:

```
App\Task::create(['title' => 'Заголовок', 'descriptions' => 'Описание', 'qrsrc' => 'бла-бла-бла']);
```

Но если Вы создаете запись с помощью модели, убедитесь, что все поля, которые Вы указываете, перечислены в классе модели в переменной [$fillable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment):

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'qrsrc'];
```

Comment: Чет не совсем понятно шаг номер 2 куда что указывать конкрентно.

Comment: Это не шаги, а 3 разных способа, которые по-своему решают проблему. Второй способ заключается в том, что Вы должны явно указывать значение поля 'qrsrc' при добавлении его в базу данных. Я подробнее расписал ответ и добавил ссылки на документацию.